# Where do the .deb files go when I select "download only" in Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: package-management, synaptic

Here is the situation. In Synaptic Package Manager, suppose I want to download package files of package_name. I follow following steps: Select package_name> Mark for installation > Accept  additional needed package installation dialogue (if any) > Apply. Then a prompt shows me which package will be installed, upgraded and removed. There is also a checkbox "Download Only". I tick it and click OK. Then it finishes downloading packages after a few minutes. My question is, where do the downloaded package goes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are downloaded into `/var/cache/apt/archives/` alongside other downloaded deb packages. To clean this folder run `apt-get clean` as root.

Comment: Or `apt-get autoclean` if you want to retain the debs of packages currently installed on your system.