# How to change Synaptic Package Manager download directory when when I select “download only”?

Tags: apt, synaptic

According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40686/where-do-the-deb-files-go-when-i-select-download-only-in-synaptic-package-man) question, I know that the `.deb` file located in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. But how to change Synaptic download directory? So when we download a package, we can locate it somewhere we want.

Answer (score 1):

To change apt cache permanently, first prepare the new directory,

```
mkdir -p /some_new_directory/partial
```

Then edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add this line,

```
dir::cache::archives /some_new_directory
```

More information here

https://abz89.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/change-an-apt-cache-folder-location/

P.S if you're too lazy to do that, simply move `/var/cache/apt/archives/` somewhere and symlink it back.

Comment: can we change the directory not in permanent way. so when we download a packages we put in a folder, so b packages in b folder. can we do something like that?